# Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I wanted to update the Django project, but I am having problems in detail post, update post and delete post

I tried lots of things, none of which has worked. I posted all my project files below. You can have look. I would be glad if you guys helps me.

**home.html**

```
              {% for droplet in  droplets %}
                <tr> 
              <td>{{ droplet.id }} </td>
              <td>{{ droplet.name}}</td>
              <td>{{ droplet.identifier }}</td>
              <td>{{ droplet.description}}</td>
              <td>{{ droplet.visibility}}</td>
              <td>{{ droplet.name_with_namespace }}</td>
              <td>{{ droplet.name_customer}}</td>
              <td>{{ droplet.status}}</td>
              <td>{{ droplet.created_at }}</td>
              
              <td>
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}

<a class="btn btn-primary badge-pill"   href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">
<i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>  
<a class="btn btn-secondary badge-pill" href="{% url 'post-update' post.id %}"><i class='far 
fa-edit'></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-danger badge-pill"    href ="{% url 'post-delete' post.id %}"> <i 
class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></a></td>{% endif %} 
   </tr>
  </tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('project/', GetDroplets.as_view(template_name='blog/home.html'), name='blog-home'),
path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-
```

delete'),
]
**views.py**

```
class GetDroplets(TemplateView):
template_name = 'blog/home.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {
        'droplets' : get_droplets(),
        'post': (value you want post to be)
    }
    return context
```

exemple for delete :

```
   class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, 
   DeleteView):

success_url = '/project/'

def test_func(self,*args, **kwargs):
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 't4eHMHShhBv6FLEXksqV'}
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    data={"name":"", "description":""}
    data=JsonResponse(data)
    response = requests.delete("http://172.16.0.111/api/v4/projects/:id", headers=headers,data=data)
    response = requests.delete("http://172.16.0.112:3000/projects/120.json", headers=headers, data = data)
    post = self.get_object()
    if self.request.user == post.author:
        return True
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)

    return False
```

Comment: share your PostDetailView

Comment: i share PostDeleteView

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Post.id does not return none or the computer will read

`<a class="btn btn-primary badge-pill"   href="{% url 'post-detail' %}">`

and not

`<a class="btn btn-primary badge-pill"   href="{% url 'post-detail' someValue %}">`

your getDroplet Class will look like this:

```
template_name = 'blog/home.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {
        'droplets' : get_droplets(),
'post': value

    }
    return context
```

Comment: The update or delete function does not appear in my database locally but with the API

Comment: make sure when you are requesting home.html you are giving it a post value

Comment: print(post.id) to console before you send it to home.html and then send the output

Comment: sorry, i don't understand

Comment: send just the code where you making a request to the file

Comment: class GetDroplets(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'droplets' : get_droplets(),
        }
        return context

Comment: ok there is no post being sent to the html file you cant pull post out of thin air so where you put  ``` 'droplets' : get_droplets(), ``` add ``` 'post': (value )``` so it will look like this   ``` 'droplets' : get_droplets(), post': (value),```

Comment: i'v edited the anwser, just change the value to whatever you want post to be

Comment: I corrected it as follows    <a class="btn btn-danger badge-pill"    href ="{% url 'post-delete' droplet.id %}"> <i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></a>
please you can check with me the function she is above ,and this is the erruer PostDeleteView is missing a QuerySet

Answer (score 0):

***views.py***

```
template_name = 'blog/home.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {
        'droplets' : get_droplets(),
        'post': (value you want post to be)
    }
    return context
```

Added post to the values sent to the HTML file as with these lines of code
post is needed for ***post.id***

````
<a class="btn btn-primary badge-pill"   href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">
<i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>  
<a class="btn btn-secondary badge-pill" href="{% url 'post-update' post.id %}"><i class='far 
fa-edit'></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-danger badge-pill"    href ="{% url 'post-delete' post.id %}"> <i 
class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></a></td>{% endif %}```
````